# how to profile large stack in go

Tags: go, profiling

I have a toy go problem i'm working on to try to learn more about go profiling. If i'm reading the profile correctly my program is spending 43% of cumulative cpu time in runtime.morestack. My understanding is that runtime.morestack should only be called when a goroutine's stack exceeds the amount allocated for it. As far as I can tell no part of my program should be using a large amount of stack space. Is there a way I can I look at how large my stacks are? (Both the size are and what variables are on each stack frame?

I've run `pprof.Lookup("goroutine").WriteTo(f, 0)` but it looks like this doesn't report the size of the stack frames or their contents.

Comment: You can get started by looking at https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#ReadMemStats and then possibly use Linux profiling tools if that is the OS you are using.

Comment: "As far as I can tell no part of my program should be using a large amount of stack space." Without code, nor can we.